# people detection / tracking (wg_perception) on indigo: easy_markers dependency

Tags: ros, tracking, markers, ros-indigo, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that Indigo's Perception package (people detection and tracking) requires dependency: easy_markers.
(two other dependencies, ros-indigo-bfl and ros-indigo-costmap-2d exists and are good).
catkin_make's  call stack: people-indigo-devel/people_velocity_tracker/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
There is not package "ros-indigo-easy-markers" for Indigo.
Out of desperation, I used "easy_markers" from wo_ros_tools_hydro, and Perception package compiles but does NOT run (does not display people, positions, produces error messages during run).
Could you please upload the "easy_markers" on GitHub?
This is the only dependency that is missing so far.
So far, David Lu has been very helpful and posted entire People Perception. We are missing 0.0001% of the stuff.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197514/people-detection-/-tracking-(wg_perception)-on-indigo:-easy_markers-dependency/) by [ROS_Portland_State_University_Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20663/ros_portland_state_university_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/DLu/wu_ros_tools

I will try to update the indigo binary soon.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROS_Portland_State_University_Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20663/ros_portland_state_university_robot/) on 2014-11-15**:
Wow, Doctor Lu! You are God! PS: it is our Portland State University robot, MCECE bot, aka Jeeves, that runs on Ubuntu and Indigo already. And our Professor says we must have Kinect working before the end of the term! Whatever is left from the "term".

**Comment by [ROS_Portland_State_University_Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20663/ros_portland_state_university_robot/) on 2014-11-15**:
'Tis strange, 'Tis strange: I installed open_ptrack (it is their People Tracking package) and it compiled and runs beautifully on Indigo. But their site does not specify that open_ptrack must use specific versions of ROS. Somehow, it compiles on any.

**Comment by [ROS_Portland_State_University_Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20663/ros_portland_state_university_robot/) on 2014-11-16**:
Warning: building CXX leg_detector.cpp.o   /face_detector/src/faces.cpp: In constructor ‘people::Faces::Faces()’:
Face; std::vector<_Tp, *Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocatorpeople::Face]’ [-Wconversion-null]
cam_model*(NULL){  : it complains that NULL is passed to a NOT-POINTER argument

**Comment by [ROS_Portland_State_University_Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20663/ros_portland_state_university_robot/) on 2014-11-16**:
Another dependency missing: kalman_filter. I used it from hydro distribution during people package installation.

**Comment by [ROS_Portland_State_University_Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20663/ros_portland_state_university_robot/) on 2014-11-16**:
'Tis strange, 'Tis strange: I installed open_ptrack (it is their version of ROS's People Tracking package) and it compiled and runs beautifully on Indigo. But their package is in directory "hydro", yet runs beautifully. Makes me wonder how their packages have forward compatibility.